# How can I differentiate between authenticated users?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am building an app that has both merchants and clients. Merchants offer their services and clients can book services from the merchants.

They BOTH are authenticated with Firebase and are on the Authentication list you can find on the Firebase Console.

On sign up, merchants' info go to a collection called 'businesses'. Clients go on a collection called 'users'.

This is how I create a 'user' document

```
async createUserProfileDocument(user, additionalData) {
    if (!user) return
    const userRef = this.firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`)
    const snapshot = await userRef.get()
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
      const { displayName, email, photoURL, providerData } = user
      const createdAt = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
      try {
        await userRef.set({
          displayName,
          email,
          photoURL,
          createdAt,
          providerData: providerData[0].providerId, //provider: 'google.com', 'password'
          ...additionalData,
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('error creating user: ', error)
      }
    }
    return this.getUserDocument(user.uid)
  }

  async getUserDocument(uid) {
    if (!uid) return null
    try {
      const userDocument = await this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
      return { uid, ...userDocument.data() }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error getting user document: ', error)
    }
  }
```

This is how 'users' sign up

```
export const Register = () => {
  const history = useHistory()

  async function writeToFirebase(email, password, values) { //function is called below
    try {
      const { user } = await firebaseService.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      firebaseService.createUserProfileDocument(user, values)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error: ', error)
    }
  }

  //Formik's onSubmit to submit a form
  function onSubmit(values, { setSubmitting }) {
    values.displayName = values.user.name
    writeToFirebase(values.user.email, values.user.password, values) //function call
  }
```

This is how a 'merchant' registers. They sign up with email + password and their info from a form go to a collection called 'businesses'

```
firebaseService.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.user.email, values.user.password)
await firebaseService.firestore.collection('businesses').add(values) //values from a form
```

Here is where I would like to be able to differentiate between 'users' and 'merchants', so that I can write some logic with the 'merchant' data. so far it only works with 'users'

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebaseService.auth.onAuthStateChanged(async function (userAuth) {
      if (userAuth) {
         //**how can I find out if this userAuth is a 'merchant' (business) or 'user' (client)
        const user = await firebaseService.createUserProfileDocument(userAuth)
        setUsername(user.displayName)
        //if (userAuth IS A MERCHANT) setUserIsMerchant(true)   **what I'd like to be able to do
      } else {
        console.log('no one signed in')
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way for implementing a role-based access control system is to use **[Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)**.

You will combine Custom Claims (and Firebase Authentication) together with [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). As explained in the doc referred to above:

> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user
>   accounts. This provides the ability to implement various access
>   control strategies, **including role-based access control**, in Firebase
>   apps. **These custom attributes can give users different levels of
>   access (roles), which are enforced in an application's security rules**.

Once you'll have assigned to your users a Custom Claim corresponding to their user role (e.g. a merchant or client Claim), you will be able to:

1. Adapt your Security Rules according to the claims;
2. Get the Claim in your front-end and act accordingly (e.g. route to specific app screens/pages, display specific UI elements, etc...)

More precisely, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client), you could do something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebaseService.auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      if (userAuth) {

         userAuth.getIdTokenResult()
         .then((idTokenResult) => {
             // Confirm the user is a Merchant or a Client
             if (!!idTokenResult.claims.merchant) {
                 // Do what needs to be done for merchants
             } else if (!!idTokenResult.claims.client) {
                 // Do what needs to be done for clients
             }
      } else {
        console.log('no one signed in')
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

---

You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which presents "How to create an Admin module for managing users access and roles" *(disclaimer, I'm the author)*.

Comment: somehow none of your code is loading on the article, unfortunately. I'll try again later. By reading the docs you provided I got another question: will I need to do some work other than just Firebase + React, e.g. using a Node backend?

Comment: "none of your code is loading on the article" -> can you give more details. If you encounter a prblem, please add a comment/question to the article itself.  "will I need to do some work other than just Firebase + React" -> As explained in the article "Custom claims should be set from a privileged server environment by the Firebase Admin SDK”. With “privileged server environment” the doc means a server that you fully control **or a Cloud Function in your Firebase Project that runs back-end code** (and that you also control, since it is in your own Project)."

Comment: Cloud Functions is totally integrated with Forebase and is "a **serverless** framework that lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features". So, no need for an extra server